# How can I access anonymous blocks (used in the render tree) with javascript and/or qtwebkit?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I access anonymous blocks (used in the render tree) with javascript (and/or qtwebkit)? It is important to me to progamatically access the computed values of all *rendered* blocks, not just of those explicitly stated in the html source.

(Anonymous blocks: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level)

Comment: In JavaScript DOM API, you're looking for a text [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

Comment: This is something specified from a purely CSS view here, it has no actual connection to the DOM – so I doubt that you will have explicit access to this with JS. As @bfavaretto said, you can of course access the first _text_ node in the scenario described in the link part of the CSS spec, but it will not be an HTMLElementNode of its own.